# .NET MAUI Splash Screen - Logo does not resize correctly and stays small

Tags: size, splash-screen, maui

I am developing in .NET MAUI (.NET 7) using Visual Studio 2022 Build 17.5.2. I am testing my first app on a Xioami Note 10 Pro as well as a Samsung S6 Lite Tablet. The API levels are 31 and 33.

I am struggling with the size of the Splash Screen Logo. I have did some extensive reading on how to configure the logo. It shows, but very small. I have changed Resize to false for the purpose of testing and I have used various BaseSize values in factors of 8 as the documentation states.

Perhaps I do not understand something correctly. From my understanding the BaseSize gives the initial size in which .NET Maui can decide to scale the vector image in. Playing with BaseSize values results in the logo to become skew, but never gets bigger. The size of the Vector according to Boxy is 1500x503. Not sure if that is the issue. I have even discarded BaseSize and still the same issue.

Appreciating your help.

UPDATE: My logo is long. Not a square. Wondering if there is a limit on the size of the logo on the Splash Screen?

Comment: Similar to this issue on Github: [Splash Screen does not resize(Scaling Issue) #4341](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug about it. Not sure if they fix it. Just edit your vector file, and use smaller version.

This will be also helpful for you, since if you use larger files, you will run into other issues:

```
<!-- Dark magic https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8609-->
<MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\home.svg" BaseSize="20,20" />
```

And last, those vectors will get converted, to PNG files. And if you use very high dimensions, this will end with too big PNG files. Some phones will start to throw memory exceptions when they try to display those PNG files.

Hard to catch and predict, runtime exceptions. So keep this in mind when you put those extremely big vectors in your project.